# Как сделать, чтобы ребёнок объекта с RigidBody не менял своё положение?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я новичок в unity. У меня проблема с rigidbody.

Есть пустой объект с RigidBody. У него есть ребёнок mainCube без rigidbody. По клику мыши должен появиться второй ребёнок куб (тоже без rigidbody) на 1 выше mainCube, но он появляется не точно на 1 выше, а на 0.99 или 1.001 и тд. Также когда начинаешь игру(нажимаешь кнопку старта) этот пустой объект меняет положение(но так вроде и должно быть, в видеоуроке видел).

Нужно, чтобы он точно на 1 менял положение.
Не знаю как это решить. Похоже на то, что дети, либо отталкиваются, либо из-за гравитации меняют положение. Причём если отключить родителю rigidbody, то всё нормально.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это вроде как изза округления или переполнения происходит в юнити такое очень часто

Comment: @KuzCode, А как это исправить?

Comment: не имею не малейшего понятия, всегда просто такая фигня